# Settings to create .app bundle for appetize / xcode / react-native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a react native build which works in simulator perfect.

I followed the steps here to product my bundled app: https://medium.com/@callMeNorm/prototyping-react-native-with-appetize-io-752f6d303668#.4sw4r2u3p - this also works in the simulator

but when I upload to https://medium.com/@callMeNorm/prototyping-react-native-with-appetize-io-752f6d303668#.4sw4r2u3p - it doesn't work with lots of debug errors - which I have no idea about - first time to build

What went wrong?

```
Log messages will follow once session has started...
2016-11-23 23:36:16.719 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Running application "Project" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ ===     true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
2016-11-23 23:36:16.807 Project[69873:5943651] -[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f859d814e00
2016-11-23 23:36:16.808 [error][tid:main][RCTUIManager.m:1140] Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized     selector sent to instance 0x7f859d814e00
2016-11-23 23:36:16.884 Project[69873:5943651] -[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f859d814e00
2016-11-23 23:36:16.886 Project[69873:5943651] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f859d814e00'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102479d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010166edeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102482d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023c8cfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023c88a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Project                             0x0000000100ea2e27 -[RCTScrollView layoutSubviews] + 1143
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000104342980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    7   QuartzCore                          0x0000000103ff9c00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    8   QuartzCore                          0x0000000103fee08e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000103fedf0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000103fe23c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104010086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00000001040107f8 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010239ec37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010239eba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023947fb __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023940f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107434ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000104287f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  Project                             0x0000000100e50acf main + 111
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010595192d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException


Log messages will follow once session has started...


Log messages will follow once session has started...


Log messages will follow once session has started...
2016-11-24 01:12:33.382 [warn][tid:main][RCTEventEmitter.m:41] Sending `websocketFailed` with no listeners registered.
2016-11-24 01:12:33.411 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Running application "Project" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
2016-11-24 01:12:33.484 Project[80101:6156279] -[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa0ce82c000
2016-11-24 01:12:33.485 [error][tid:main][RCTUIManager.m:1140] Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa0ce82c000
2016-11-24 01:12:33.496 Project[80101:6156279] -[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa0ce82c000
2016-11-24 01:12:33.499 Project[80101:6156279] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa0ce82c000'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010539cd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104591deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001053a5d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001052ebcfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001052eb8a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Project                             0x0000000103dc5e27 -[RCTScrollView layoutSubviews] + 1143
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000107265980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    7   QuartzCore                          0x0000000106f1cc00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    8   QuartzCore                          0x0000000106f1108e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000106f10f0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106f053c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106f33086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000106f337f8 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001052c1c37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001052c1ba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001052b77fb __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001052b70f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a357ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001071aaf09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  Project                             0x0000000103d73acf main + 111
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010887492d start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)   
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 1):

@agua2489 I am also getting the same issue. Please update if you were able to resolve it. Thanks.

Scenario is a little different for me though. If I use `<ListView>` on my home page it shows this error. As soon as I remove `<ListView>`, error is gone. Not sure whats happening there.

[image: ios error]